# Dependencies per project vs per distribution package

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am working on a Python project. But I don't know changing the dependencies for subsequent releases is something to consider or not. So should I fix the dependencies before building the first distribution package or there is no problem changing the dependencies for future updates?

Comment: You can set new dependencies for each new release.

Comment: Thank you @sinoroc. You are the only one who answering my recent questions.